# Windows phone emulator not working (visual studio update 3)?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, xamarin, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

2 days ago I installed Visual studio update 3 with select all on windows 8.1 proX64 .Yesterday and day before yesterday emulator was working fine but from today morning it's not working and showing about 4 to 5 Minutes and automatically shutdown VM but when I start VM from hyper-v manager then it works fine . Today morning I installed [XAMARIN studio](http://xamarin.com/) .

**windows phone OS is starting .....**

http://i.picresize.com/images/2014/11/08/G2q50.png
It's not freezing i.e. rotation , close is working . It runs for more than ten minutes then visual studio gives following error messages.

**Error 1   Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device':
SmartDeviceException - App deployment failed. Please try again.     

Error   2   Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found. App deployment failed. Please try again.**

**I tried following methods to solve but none of them works .**
After closing visual studio 
1. Delete all virtual machine from Hyper-v manager and delete switch from virtual machone manager and restart PC and Visual studio .
2. Repair windows phone emulator from control panel uninstall or change program and restarted pc .
3. Direct run from Hyper-v manager .
4. Unistalling and installing windows phone SDK. Restart windows OS

How to fix this error ?

Comment: this problem was occurred due to XAMARIN installation . I tried all sorts of answer available on net  to solve this problem . Finally i just through away .

Answer (score 0):

You see this error when there are pending updates that has to be installed on the machine. Make sure you have installed all Windows updates and also VS 2013 updates and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: sorry! for late reply , it was up to date at that time .